# How To Minimize My Application To System Tray In C#?

Tags: c#

I'm sorry, I speak a little English.

The button3_Click is work, but the Form1_Resize it does not work.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;

namespace FirstApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                this.Hide();
                notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Why? What is the problem?

I'm beginner in C#, sorry.

Comment: Did you write this code yourself or did you copy it?  If you copied it then the site license requires you to provide a link to the source.  And as a bonus, everybody will know what you forgot to do.

Comment: For the 'Resize' event to work, the condition to enter is that the Window is minimized. It may be hard to 'Resize' a window that is not displayed on screen, unless you do it programmatically but this is another story.

Comment: @Hazrelle This code should work.  The event probably isn't subscribed.  The user should override the `OnResize` method instead to avoid that issue.